# Creating AVD screen based on physical device

Tags: android

I have a Android tablet and I want to create an Android Virtual Device (AVD) whose screen is as close to the physic device as possible (in terms of size and resolution).

I tried copying the resolution from the device settings, but the size of things in the emulator screen still look different. The device reports it's density is xlarge, but (as far as I understand) these density aliases are approximations anyway.

Is there a way (even an app that I would install on the device) to know what settings I have to create the AVD with to get a equivalent screen?

The device is not from a major manufacturer, it's unlikely that I will find a 'ready-made' AVD.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to manually set the width and height of a screen in the AVD Manager. I found that even when I had put those in correctly, my virtual device still didn't look right.

Only when I put in the "size" would it work correctly. The "size" is a diagonal measurement from opposite corners of the device's screen. 
For example: From the top left corner to the bottom right.

I realize that this may be an old post, but someone may stumble upon it.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the AVD Manager and create New... device you can set the screen size by adjusting manually the Skin Resolution.
Once you start that device it will ask you if you want to use that resolution or adjust to actual screen size.